# Dynamically Re-arrange Panel Postions in Bootstrap.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

This Bootstrap trick I am seeking can be phrased as follows. Let's say we have two rows that contain several panels. When one panel is dismissed, I'd like to see the neighbouring panel automatically fills the space taken by the previous one. For example: if a panel on the left is dismissed, the one on the right moves to the left. It is a bit like in iPhone, when one App icon is dismissed, the rest reshuffles. I have been searched the internet for a while without success.

Just for a reference, part of my current layout looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-group" id="contentPanel">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="">
        <div class="panel panel-info" id="indexPanel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <span id="indexPanelHeading">Panel 1</span>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#indexPanel" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span class="pull-right clickable">
                  <i id="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            </div>
          </div> <!--end of panel-heading -->
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4>Some texts </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--another panel -->  
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="">
        <div class="panel panel-info" id="indexPanel2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <span id="indexPanelHeading2">Panel 2</span>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#indexPanel2" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span class="pull-right clickable">
                  <i id="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            </div>
          </div> <!--end of panel-heading -->
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4>Some texts</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to remove the parent `col-*` when a panel is dismissed..

```
$('.close').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();  
   var $target = $(this).parents('.col-sm-3');
   $target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
});
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/eWpdCAJsHr

Example with dynamically created cols..

http://www.codeply.com/go/pUN5oATSFb

Comment: Interesting solution. One thing I forgot to point out is that the the panel within <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style=""> is generated dynamically using jQuery. I thought there shall be no difference. But somehow this solution seems a bit awkward in this setting.

Comment: Do you mean it's not working with your dynamically created cols? Or you just don't like the solution?

Comment: ZimSystem, please don't take it the wrong way. I definitely like the solution since it works for static cols. But it somehow doesn't work with the dynamically generated cols.

Comment: Ok, just make sure you bind the `click` event after the dynamic cols are generated. I will update the answer with an example